# Would removing and reinstalling the Crank Position Sensor cause a Chevy Vortec to run poorly?

Tags: chevrolet, crank-position-sensor, express-van

To troubleshoot a high RPM issue with my Chevy Vortec 4.3L V6 motor has been experiencing, I performed a compression test, leakdown test, and pulled the crank position sensor to inspect it for damage.  FWIW, it passed both the compression test and leakdown test.

After I re-installed the spark plugs, wires and crank position sensor, the engine has been running **very** poorly.  There's a tapping/knocking sound and a squeal that seems correlated to crank speed.  Additionally, there's a ton of misfires at idle, which seem mostly limited to the #3 cylinder (I got about 1850+ misfires on Cyl #3 in the 2 minutes it took to pull out of my driveway and park on the street).  The noises do seem to be coming from the left bank, which has the #3 cylinder.

Again, these symptoms did not exist before I did the compression test, leakdown test and inspected the crank position sensor.

My understanding is that any time the crank position sensor is replaced or even distributed, a crank position sensor relearn procedure (CASE relearn) should be performed.  I never had the relearn done.  My limited understanding says that the crank relearn is only for misfire detection, and in my area, this procedure is quite expensive, so I don't want to do it if it won't help.

Could these symptoms caused by the crank sensor relearn not being done?

Comment: Perhaps that screwdriver is going up and down...

Comment: Try swapping the plug from #3 with another cylinder and see if the misfire continues on #3 or moves. Is the CPS properly fitted and connected?

Comment: No part of [that screwdriver](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/81264/finding-tdc-with-a-screwdriver-what-if-screwdriver-gets-stuck) was left behind.

Yes, the CPS/CKP is properly fitted and connected.

Comment: Did you move the plug?

Comment: Yes.  Moving the plug made no difference @SolarMike

Comment: What codes are being pulled?

Comment: P0300, sometimes P0303. Nothing else